# jquery closest not working for form

Tags: jquery, html, closest

I have the following code which you're able to see what I am trying to do is add the form code inside the form but because the form changes ID, I wanted to use `closest();`

```
$("#contentarea").closest("form").html("some code");
```

DEMO
http://jsfiddle.net/zQC2Q/

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context to make this question answerable. How about posting your HTML?

Comment: could you post an example with jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: Where is your html? And what do you expect?

Comment: How can you ask this with a straight face? "jquery closest not working" you give no html, and the only jquery you use doesn't involve `.closest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you choose jQuery in the left panel on your demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/zQC2Q/3/

You had it left as Mootools